# How do I rename a network interface using netsh?

Tags: windows-server-2008, netsh, ipv4, windows-server-core

I'm building my first Windows 2008 Server Core machine (running R2) and want to rename the IPv4 network interfaces to something more meaningful.

It seems most likely that this is done using `netsh interface ipv4 set` but looking through the help hasn't turned anything up.

Could someone please advise the correct procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a 2008 machine handy at the moment, but I believe it's something like this:

```
netsh interface set interface name = "{old name here}" newname = "{newname here}"
```